# Placement new on existing buffer

Tags: c++, new-operator

First question, hope i managed to phrase it right.

While checking to see if i can "force" a buffer to behave as a class (with inheritance and vptr) , i tried the following code:

I defined the following classes:

```
class a
{
    public:

    char strBuff[50];
    virtual void boo() = 0;

};

class b : public a
{
    public:
    virtual void boo()
    {
        printf("%s\n", strBuff);
    }
};
```

And used them like this:

```
int main()
{
    char buffer_allo[100] = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    b* obj_Ptr = (b*)(buffer_allo);

    // Placement new
    new (obj_Ptr) b();

    // Calling virtual function
    obj_Ptr->boo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is empty, as in a `\0` buffer, and i couldn't exactly figure out why.

I thought it was some thing of a default-initialization\ value-initialization problem, and indeed changing the placement new from `new (obj_Ptr) b();` to
`new (obj_Ptr) b;`
 didn't give a blank output, but a buffer where just the first 8 characters were overwritten (Probably by the vptr),

But then, i tried adding a constructor to either class, and discovered that adding an empty constructor to class b, will also prevent the buffer from being initialized with `\0`, but adding a constructor to class a seems to have no effect.

Why is this happening? is it really an initialization issue? and if so, why does adding an empty constructor solve it? or is it a compiler\c++ standard issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/620137/1171191

Comment: It should be `b* obj_Ptr =  new (buffer_allo) b();` not that ugly cast

Comment: " is it really an initialization issue?" no it is issue of you invoking UB

Comment: If the `buffer_allo` is not correctly aligned for `b` then there is also UB

Comment: You can't "reuse" the original string, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Point taken @Slava, it is an ugly cast, but how is it UB? if you too are referring to the size mismatch between the buffers, it was just an example, to see if such a thing is possible.

Comment: @PasserBy are you sure? because removing the parentheses and using the new seems to work, as referenced by the similar question

Comment: @TomRonen Different context, same deal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Comment: @TomRonen you are reading from unintialized member - that is UB

Comment: @TomRonen There is nothing in your code that legitimately initialises `strBuff`. I guess you're expecting it to have the content of `buffer_allo` but nothing in C++ says that will be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is that dark area of C++ initialization rules. They are quite intricate and you can read them in cppreference.

Basically, when you call placement new - `new (obj_Ptr) b();` (with an empty pair of parentheses) value initialization takes place. According to the standard:

> 1) if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>
> 2) if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted **(that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized** and then it is default-initialized if it has a non-trivial default constructor;
>
> 3) if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
>
> 4) otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Since it is zero-initialized this is what you see when you call `obj_Ptr->boo();`. When you define you own constructor the object is default-initialized, and hence your buffer contains garbage. This is basically it.
More detailed explanation: [value initialization in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Also, not related to the question, but I would like to mention a couple of things.

1) As Slava pointed out, it is better to use return from placement new directly, without any casts, like this: `auto obj_Ptr = new(buffer_allo) b();`

2) Try to avoid keyword `virtual` for the method of derived class. It is better to use `override`, since it is clearer and can catch mistakes when you accidentally create new function in the derived class instead of overriding the one in the base. Like this: `void boo() override{...}`